# Questions about the proof of the Gauss-Bonnet Theorem for surfaces with boundary

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, stokes-theorem, manifolds-with-boundary

(This comes from the proof of the Gauss-Bonnet Theorem for surfaces with boundary. See Do Carmo's 'Differential Forms and Applications' Chapter 6, Theorem 2.)

---

Let $M$ be an oriented, compact, two-dimensional differentiable manifold with boundary $\partial M$.

Let $X$ be a differentiable vector field on $M$ such that it is transversal to $\partial M$.
Now choose a metric on $M$ and consider in $M$ the orthonormal oriented moving frame $\bar{e}_1=X/|X|,\; \bar{e}_2$.

Choose in a neighborhood $V\subset M$ of $\partial M$ another oriented moving frame $e_1,e_2$ such that restricted to $\partial M$, $e_1$ is tangent to $\partial M$. Then

$$
i^*\bar{\omega}_{12}=i^*\omega_{12}+d\phi
$$
where $i:\partial M\to M$ is the inclusion map, and $\phi$ is the angle between $\bar{e}_1$ and $e_1$ along $\partial M$.

Then in the proof of the Gauss-Bonnet Theorem for surfaces with boundary. A key step states that:

> Since $\bar{e}_1=X/|X|$ is nowhere tangent to $\partial M$, $\int_{\partial M}d\phi=0$.

This statement confuses me.

**My main question is, how to prove this statement?**

---

My initial thought is, by Stokes Theorem, it seems that $\int_{\partial M}d\phi=\int_{M} d^2\phi=0$ is always true, soon I realized that $d\phi$ is not a 1-form defined in $M$.

So my second question is, if there are two moving frames $\{e_1,e_2\}$ and $\{\bar{e}_1,\bar{e}_2\}$ satisfying:

$$
\bar{e}_1=fe_1+ge_2\\
\bar{e}_2=-ge_1+fe_2
$$

with $f,g$ being differentiable functions, and $f^2+g^2=1$, then the connection forms satisfy:

$$
\omega_{12}=\bar{\omega}_{12}-\tau
$$

where $\tau$ is the differential of the "angle function" between $e_1$ and $\bar{e}_1$ along a curve.

**My question is, is the 1-form $\tau$ exact?**

---

Again, I think the answer should be no. For instance, the differential of the "angle function" in $R^2$ is closed but not exact, since it is defined in $R^2-\{0\}$, but I still struggle to prove this in a more general 2-d manifold.

---

It is a long post, thank you for reading, and any hints are appreciated!

Comment: It *is* exact when your "angle function" is actually a *function* on all of $\partial M$. The fact that $\bar e_1$ is never equal to $\pm e_1$ tells you that $\bar e_1$ cannot make a full revolution and return to its original position. That is, $\phi$ is always in one of the intervals $(0,\pi)$ or $(-\pi,0)$. (Remember that $\phi$ is smooth, so, in particular, continuous.)